# Look for a process with a given name

Tags: linux, ps

I am trying to convert the VMS command `show/system/process=processname` into an equivalent Linux command.

I tried the following but it returned none of the processes:

```
ps -C /exeimages/processname.pl
```

Answer (score 7):

`ps -C` looks for an exact match of the basename of the executable at the time if was executed. So, in this case, `ps -C perl` or `ps -C processname.pl` would more likely be what you want. What matters is what you find in `/proc/<pid>/stat`.

If you want to match on the command line (the concatenation of the arguments of the command including `argv[0]`), you can use `pgrep -f` as found on Solaris, recent Linux and most BSDs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for `pgrep`, or something cobbled together from that and `ps`